# How to handle RuntimeException within a thread

Tags: java, exception, java-threads

I am not sure what's the best way to handle `RuntimeException` in a thread.
Let's say I have a thread A, which uses a 3rd party function `b()` to send data to a server S. Now `b()` can throw some RuntimeException and fail to push data to the designated server. In that case, I have to run a method `c()` which pushes data to a local database. Now method `c()` can also throw a `RuntimeException` if it's not able to write to the db.

Example:

```
public class A() extends Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // throws some specific RuntimeExceptions in case it fails  
        b(data, "<some https end point>");
    } 
}
```

Now in case `b()` doesn't work as expected, I have to execute method `c()`.

One way to handle this is wrap `b()` and `c()` around a try-catch block and catch a RuntimeException as following

```
    public void run() {
        // throws some specific RuntimeExceptions in case it fails 
        try {
        b(data, "<some https end point>");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
             try {
               c(data)
             } catch(RuntimeException e) {
                //Log the error
             }
        }
    }
```

Though this works, I am not very comfortable with catching generic exceptions this way. Other suggestions seem to be handling exceptions via Future objects (when submitting to some executor service). Is this a better practice? If so, why?

Comment: Note: if `B` and `C` are methods, then they should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I have made the edit

Answer (score 0):

If the methods `B` and `C` throw subclass(es) of `RuntimeException`, catch those excepetions. Use `e.getClass().getName()` to find out which RuntimeExceptions you get, and handle them appropriately.

I'd say that methods that throw 'pure' `RuntimeExcpetions` are not well written. But methods that throw `Exceptions` that *inherit* from `RunttimeException` (such as `NumberFormatException`) might be well designed (see the link below for simple tips). Hopefully `B` and `C` are well designed.

For easy-to-read info that relate to your question, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: I understand your point. But the problem with this is that the methods you use can be using other methods which in turn throw different subclasses of RunTimeException. I can't possibly know all possible exceptions, right?

Comment: You are right, but that applies for all methods (in 3rd party libs and in your own code). The idea (at least one of them) behind the RuntimeExceptions is that it is unreasonable to catch everything everywhere. If you get a RuntimeException, you should assume that it is because something is wrong with the code (someone forgets to check if a==0 before they do b/a, etc). If possible, that programming error should be handled. If that's not possible, you can catch the exception and do a work-around implementation. Best way to find which RuntimeExceptions are thrown by 3rd party is probably testing.

Comment: Let's consider an example where the 3rd party method I use throws an `SSLException` in case there is a problem when it is not able to contact the server via https. This is clearly a runtime exception. I still want to handle it. What do you suggest one does in that case? There isn't any programming error in the client code.

Comment: A correction. Came to know that `SSLException` is not a `RuntimeException`. In my case it's wrapped with another `FailsafeException` (which is a runtime).

Comment: Then I suggest you catch `FailsafeException` (not `RuntimeException`) and do "something appropriate", eg print an error message, set a boolean that tells the thread to interrupt, trigger a listener, etc. If you are using `FailsafeException` for other error situations too, you can add `isSSLProblem()` to your `FailsafeException` and use it to produce a better error message etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never catch a `RuntimeException` because they are not meant to be caught. They indicate a problem with your algorithm, when you see it you should go and fix your code.
Any library that's throwing a RuntimeException for expected failure cases is not designed well.

If you're building a solution just to keep your thread working (because you have to use a ill-designed library), surround the method call with try-catch block which will catch both checked and unchecked exceptions.

Comment: But isn't that common? For example, the 3rd party method I use throws an `SSLException`  in case there is some problem when the method is not able to contact the server via https. This is clearly a runtime exception, right? But I still want to handle it.

Comment: @user1955184 `SSLException` is not a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @EJB My bad. You are right. I am using the `FailSafe` library to do retries which wraps the `SSLException` with `FailsafeException` (which is a `RuntimeException`)